# Webscrape from 2500 links - courses of action?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have nearly 2500 unique links, from which I want to run BeautifulSoup and gather some text captured in paragraphs on each of the 2500 pages. I could create variables for each link, but having 2500 is obviously not the most efficient course of action. The links are contained in a list like the following:

```
linkslist = ["http://www.website.com/category/item1","http://www.website.com/category/item2","http://www.website.com/category/item3", ...]
```

Should I just write a `for` loop like the following?

```
for link in linkslist:
    opened_url = urllib2.urlopen(link).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(opened_url)
...
```

I'm looking for any constructive criticism. Thanks!

Comment: maybe you could try concurrent.futures module

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for [`Scrapy`](http://scrapy.org/) - a popular web-scraping framework based on `Twisted`:

> Scrapy is written with Twisted, a popular event-driven networking
>   framework for Python. Thus, it’s implemented using a **non-blocking** (aka
>   asynchronous) code for concurrency.

Set the `start_urls` property of your spider and parse the page inside the `parse()` callback:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    start_urls = ["http://www.website.com/category/item1","http://www.website.com/category/item2","http://www.website.com/category/item3", ...]
    allowed_domains = ["website.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        print response.xpath("//title/text()").extract()
```

Comment: Shoot. That would be good. I need to find a way to import `Scrapy` into my Anaconda IDE, then.

Comment: @GBR24 one of multiple advantages is that it's easy to get started - no need to dive into multiprocessing and write any "page retrieval" code at all. Scrapy has it all inside providing a nice and easy interface on top.

Answer (score 1):

How about writing a function that would treat each URL separately?

```
def processURL(url):
    pass
    # Your code here
map(processURL, linkslist)
```

This will run your function on each url in your list. If you want to speed things up, this is easy to run in parallel:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
list(Pool(processes = 10).map(processURL, linkslist))
```

Comment: I'm pretty unfamiliar with writing functions. What does the function processURL(url) actually do? Is simply writing a `for` loop inadequate for a list of links of this magnitude?

Comment: You can certainly accomplish this with a for loop. However, I believe that reasoning in terms of functions would make it much easier for you to think about your code. All you need to do is to copy the code you would normally place after `for` statement into a function body. Think of it as: `for url in linkslist: processURL(url)`. This still leaves you to handle the parsing of the web page.